# Got error when installation cocoapod in acOS CATALINA

Tags: ios, rubygems, cocoapods

appedifytechnoworld@AppEdifys-MacBook-Air ~ % pod version
zsh: command not found: pod
appedifytechnoworld@AppEdifys-MacBook-Air ~ % pod --version
zsh: command not found: pod
appedifytechnoworld@AppEdifys-MacBook-Air ~ % sudo gem install cocoapods

Password:
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.13.1/ext/ffi_c
```

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20200923-7613-1he2flb.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

You might have to install separate package for the ruby development
environment, ruby-dev or ruby-devel for example.

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/ffi-1.13.1/gem_make.out
appedifytechnoworld@AppEdifys-MacBook-Air ~ %